# How to pass page as an argument like post in WordPress?

Tags: custom-field, pages

I am using this code to pass arguments in posts:

```
$args_automobile_just_launched_bike = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'wpcf-new-launch-bikes',
            'value' => '1',
        ),
    ),
);
```

This is the format of getting posts dynamically.
How can I do the same for Page?

Comment: Replace `'post_type'=> 'post'` with `'post_type'=> 'page'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pages are posts, you just need to change the `post_type` to `page`:

```
$args_automobile_just_launched_bike = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'wpcf-new-launch-bikes',
            'value' => '1',
        ),
    ),
);
```